# у меня не работает метод upper()

Tags: python

```
S = input()
S.upper()
print(S)
```

Кто может сказать почему в пайчарме, когда я ввожу любую строку  метод upper() не работает, то есть при вводе строки выводит:

dajdajd
dajdajd

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Что именно не работает? Выдаёт ошибку? Текст не увеличивается? Вот ссылка на документацию https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/upper

Comment: По тому кусочку, который вы приложили, можно понять, что текст вы увеличили, но никуда его не присвоили. S = S.upper(). Добавьте присвоение в эту же или в другую/новую переменную

Comment: Итого, внимательно читаем документацию. измененная копия строки является возвращаемым значением. Поэтому и советуют выше добавить присвоение.

Comment: В вашем случае должно быть `S = S.upper()`

Answer (score 1):

В твоем случае вот корректный код:

```py
S = input().upper()

print(S)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, теперь работает.